How can maximum kinetic energy not equal to total energy in SHM$?$

A linear harmonic oscillator of force constant $2×10^6$$ \,\text{N}\,\text{m}^{-1}$ and amplitude $0.01 \,\text{m}$ has a total mechanical energy of $160 \,\text{J}$. Find ratio of maximum potential energy to maximum kinetic energy.

According to the laws of SHM, the total mechanical energy is constant. When kinetic energy is maximum, potential energy is $0$ and vice-versa so the answer should be $1$. But it's not the same as the given solution!
The given solution said:

As we know that, total mechanical energy is equal to maximum potential energy$=160 \,\text{J}$ and maximum kinetic energy will be $kA^2/2$ which will be equal to $100 \,\text{J}$ so the ratio will be $1.6$.


How is this even possible? First of all, how is maximum kinetic energy not equal to total energy? I am having a hard time digesting this fact. Because when a simple pendulum undergoes the same thing we have different results. I guess that it has something to do with the device i.e. the linear harmonic oscillator, I am not sure though.
Pls tell how the maximum KE is not equal to total mechanical energy. Any help is greatly appreciated.
This is not a homework question. I am trying to understand the concept used and not the calculations required.

The problem is self-contradictory. An oscillator with the given spring constant and amplitude does not have 160 J of mechanical energy.

Is this really the entire context of the problem?  Is this a vertical spring where we have to take into account gravitational potential energy? Is it a physical spring where we have to take into account the mass of the spring? Etc. I suspect perhaps for this problem to make sense that this is a hanging spring and there is some gravitational potential energy. But without that context, as stated, it's either obviously contradictory or we have to make some assumptions to make sense of the answer.

@march it was the full problem...even I think that the problem is flawed

I think so too. Where did the problem come from?

Voting to close for lack of details for now as the question and given solution, as currently stated, clearly make no sense. Refer to my first comment above.

You need to post the book title and the authors, or whatever the source of this question is. Then: promptly ignore that source.

@JEB these undergrad question makers are mostly dumb....for making a question tricky and tough they even forget physics and post some bullshit as the question

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad that's why I want the source! There is a motivation, though, for these mixed up questions and often ridiculous word problems (though that's more of a math thing).

Total energy = Kinetic energy + Potential energy
At mean position, KE is maximum and PE is minimum.
If PE at this mean position is taken zero, then the kinetic energy (at mean position) will be equal to total energy.

This seems like a bit of a trick question, but I would interpret it by asking "what do they mean by potential energy?"  In the most strictest sense, we like to measure potential energy by starting infinitely far away and seeing the work done on the way to the configuration.  This typically leads to very large negative numbers in the megajoules or gigajoules range.  Given that your problem doesn't have that, they're probably taking it with respect to some arbitrary reference altitude.
If this is true, then its reasonable to say that the potential energy is not zero at the point of maximum velocity.  It's the lowest the energy will get with the spring intact, but were we to cut the spring, the mass could fall to this lower reference altitude.
An odd question, for sure.  But applicable if you're holding the mass-spring oscillator in your hands and you're thinking in terms of how much energy might be released were you to lose control and let the device hit the floor.

This is a simple harmonic oscillator. The maximum potential energy for the given amplitude is 100 J. The problem as currently stated is self-contradictory.

@VincentThacker this question (the book, not OP) is so whack, I would go relativistic and just say the a ratio is $R \approx \frac 1 2 kA^2 / mc^2 $ with $m = k/\omega^2$...wait, can we not get $m$ because the problem doesn't specify a period?
